# FormGroup expects a from group instance ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHVwR.png)[Image of template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezb0Q.png)

this image is a copy of my html file cant seem resolve this issue
2nd image is my ts file

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Can you create a https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Do not put images of code, please edit your question and put the code in, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line on your template, you have `formgroup` in lower case, instead of `formGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

In the template you misspell the value of form. Set that line with this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="saveNote(formGroup.value)">
```

Also a good practice when implement Template Reactive is import

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
```

and inject "FormBuilder" into the constructor,

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder)
```

This is to use the benefits of depencency injection (DI), one of the main core of this framework.

So you don't have to create a new class ( clases defined in angular with @injector() metadata ) , just let angular does it in backstage.

Have fun coding.